# SwitchMap with DebounceTime

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm implementing some search and filtering controls with Angular. I've started using RxJs for this. First I had really bad time trying to understand operators like `switchMap` and `exauhstMap`, so I referred to this [video](https://youtu.be/rUZ9CjcaCEw) and this [article](https://medium.com/@shairez/a-super-ninja-trick-to-learn-rxjss-switchmap-mergemap-concatmap-and-exhaustmap-forever-88e178a75f1b). Now I have better understanding of it. But a question popped up on my mind regarding using `debounceTime()` with `switchMap()`. Is it a common practice? Why do I need a debounceTime when switchMap will make sure to cancel all previous requests?

So if I'm implementing a search box like Google's, would I need to use both?

Comment: `debounceTime` is useful so you don't make so many backend requests. Even if you would cancel them with `switchMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of using `debounceTime` is to spare your back-end. If you send a request it doesn't matter for the BE if the response is got and handled be the FE. The request is there and it has to be handled by the BE.

In the search and filter functionality you know that you don't need to do anything while the user is typing (search functionality). So that's why you use `debounceTime`

Comment: So that means I'm using debounceTime for the backend and switchMap for the frontend? If I got this clearly?

Comment: Not sure if we understand each other. You do both on the FE, but `debounceTime` is more for removing unnecessary requests, hence you're loading the BE less. Hope it answers your question.